# Pairing with a mac results in visual studio freezing

Tags: c#, ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I have an app that was developed using Xamarin on Visual Studio (17.7.1 & 17.7.3) and I want to publish it on the App Store for Apple and to do that I need to pair with a mac. Now, as the title suggests this results in visual studio freezing forever, as of now it has been frozen for a bit over two and a half hours.

The program has gone completely unresponsive and I emphasize this since I have not found anything on google that describes what I experience, it doesn't crash or gets stuck in an infinite loop, it just freezes.

The step it freezes at is "Starting IDB *IP*..." and then nothing. I have tried a handful of things which include

1. Uninstalling Xamarin from MAC through the terminal
2. Shutting down both machines and booting them back up
3. Deleting the bin and obj folders from the solution
4. Multiple tries (40 times at least)
5. Turning off hot reload and remote simulator
6. Rolling back the version of Visual Studio to 17.7.3 to 17.7.1
7. Combinations of all the above

Now, I have tried more things but they were random and I did that just because I could, like removing and adding my apple account again. I should also note that I do not have this issue while pairing to the mac with another project of mine developed on MAUI, it is just this project that runs on Xamarin.

More info about my setup include

- The project runs on .NET 6
- The mac in question has Xcode 14.2
- The mac has macOS Monterey version 12.6.8
- Before the "Starting IDB *IP*..." messages appears it says "An error occurred while registering a handler for remote exception messages, so the remote errors content will not be handled in this active connection"

Any help on how to resolve this pairing issue will be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Try starting Visual Studio by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  See if error changes or goes away.  I'm not sure this will fix the locking, but I suspect the error is occurring because you are not an Admin.  When executing a executable outside VS it will inherit Admin, but not inside VS.

Comment: You may refer to [Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac). Then restart Visual Studio and pair to Mac again.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I have tried both of those things (the other being what jdweng recommended) two times, one with visual studio being run with administrator privileges and deleting the XMA cache and the other doing the same thing but without administrator privileges. It still results on visual studio freezing.

Comment: Does it freeze if you create a project with the default template?

Comment: No, no it doesn't, which is weird since I did run the application on the simulator for iOS before. I will try to narrow down the problem and report back what is at fault which might take a couple of hours or hell, even days.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT You are a life saver, I just copied all the info I could from the new project .csproj file for iOS to the old one, deleted all bin and obj files including the .vs one for good measure. After that I pressed the connect button and it didn't freeze, it connected successfully.

I cannot stress this enough, thank you.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Have a great day!

Comment: I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 17 and this required a newer Xcode version. Since the new Xcode version this problem shows up. I guess MS needs to fix things again to make it work with the latest Xcode release.

Answer (score 6):

I've gotten the hanging behavior with the "An error occurred while registering a handler for remote exception messages, so the remote errors content will not be handled in this active connection" message connecting to a Mac which only happened on specific mobile solutions.  Clearing out the .vs files associated with the solution that had the problem corrected the issue here.